# A simple java program to find the largest prime factor of a large number(here 600851475143) compiled with no errors but not giving any output

Tags: java, output

I'm not finding any fault with my program. Please point out my mistake and help me.

Code is written below:

```
class largest
    {
    public static void main(String...args)
        {
        double n,i,f=1.0;
        n=600851475143L;
        largest ob= new largest();
         for(i=n/4;i<n/2;i++)
            {
            if(n%i==0)
                {
                  if(ob.isprime(i) == 1)
                    f=i;
                }
            }
        System.out.println(f);
        }
    int isprime(double k)
        {
        int s,i=2,flag=0;
        while(i<k && flag==0)
            {
            if(k%i==0)
                 flag=1;
            }
        if(flag==0)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger to trace through the program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function `isprime` is in most cases an endless loop. It never increments `i` in the loop.

Every time you write a loop, you should think about the so called [loop variant](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_variant). This is numerical property of the loop, that is both:

1. A positive integer in each loop run
2. Decreasing during successive iterations of the loop

If you cannot think about such a property, you are in big trouble, because you have very likely an endless loop.

In your example, that property should be the number whose prime factor you want minus the current prime factor candidate you are checking.

In your current code, if you calculate the loop variant, you will get a positive integer (good), but it will not decrease (bad). As an consequence, you will wait forever, because you have an endless loop.

While other answers show nice solutions to make your code more efficient, this won't help you very much: an efficient endless loop still won't give you any result.

Comment: True but not a complete answer .. code is still to slow to run

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @shadyyx I think this answers exactly the question, why the code is never giving an answer, independently how long one waits for it. In principle you are right, but in this case I will not give a complete answer, because it is obviously a homework question.

Comment: +1. A *complete* answer cannot be given without reference to number theory and, a few years ago, would have been a good PhD thesis. The algorithm itself is at fault let alone the implementation. I believe this answer is sufficient for the OP. By the way, if anyone figures out how to factorise a semi-prime number quickly then they'd certainly be as famous as any 20th century mathematician!

Comment: @stefan.schwetschke When I was flagging this answer, it contained only the first sentence (**only**) and to me it seemed more like a comment than an answer. It is very nice that you have extended the commentary into a good answer but I cannot retract my flag vote.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is far too slow, that's why it takes so much time to execute and doesn't return any output (apparently). You should speed up your `isPrime` test using the following trick : if n is not a prime, it can be written as n = p x q where p <= sqrt(n) and q > p. Then, **you can stop your loop at sqrt(n)** since you are able to tell that n is not a prime if there is no integer p <= sqrt(n) verifying this property.

The following code uses that remark but also another property : a integer can always be written as 6*p + q where p and q are integers and q < 6. For all p, 6*p + 2 and 6*p + 4 are divisible by 2 and 6*p + 3 is divisible by 3 so for all n = 6*p + q, if n is not divisible by 2 nor by 3, then n has the form 6*p + 1 of 6*p + 5 (or 6*p - 1, which is equivalent).

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if (n == 2 || n == 3)
        return true;
    if(n <= 1 || n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0)
        return false;
    int x = (int) Math.sqrt(n);
    for(int i=1 ; (6*i-1) <= x ; i++)
        if(n % (6*i-1) == 0 || n % (6*i+1) == 0) 
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

**Edit :**

Plus, as stefan.schwetschke observed, you are not incrementing the index of your loop. In this case you should use a for loop since you now exactly the bounds of the index of the loop.

Comment: Umm . you would have found "7" when you checked "2"

Comment: @splungebob : it was for you, he gave you the answer. In fact, the algorithm I'm proposing is correct but the explanation is formulated in a way it seems to be wrong. I am going to edit it, thanks for your observation.

Comment: The loop goes from 2 to sqrt(n), so it is fine for 25. This trick is well-known for the primality test.

Comment: Ok, now that you've improved the wording of your post, I upvoted instead of downvoted. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for helping me to correct my answer !

Answer (score 0):

This is not a "code" answer (none of the other answers will provide a solution in a reasonable amount of time , even when correcting your brute force original code).

You may want to explore prime factorization algorithms, with Pollard-Strassen algorithm (or Rho Pollard algorithm).

Some research links include:

- Wolfram Research http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PollardRhoFactorizationMethod.html
- Colorado State University lecture http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~srirams/classes/doku.php/pollard_rho_tutorial

and here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185524/pollard-strassen-algorithm 
(for mathematics on stackexchange.